# How to use SD Card in M10 OTA-11?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sd-card, m10

Is there any way how to configure ANY of the applications to utilize SD-Card? Currently I can copy music there, what about any of the writing/note-taking tools?

At the moment M10 storage is OK, but if I REALLY start to use it, I'm afraid that the device will be cluttered with files, music and pictures...

This is exactly what happened to my previous, Android tablet. Quite decent hardware, still working OK, but Android dies because not enough memory. And at the same time there sits a 32GB SD card with 95% free capacity.

Is Ubuntu Touch running to the same trap....

Comment: Are you meaning to ask if there is a way to store system files on the SD card?

Answer (score 0):

So far I've only seen SD offered as place to store data only in Camera. Other apps, or some system wide setting would be nice. System files can stay where they are, no desire to move them around...

Answer (score 0):

Have only seen the camera app offer an option to direct files to the SD card. 
However, can use the File Manager App to cut/paste files between M10 and the SD card. Can eject the SD card, mount on another computer, and add/remove files using the other computer.